# Error: Can't resolve lodash-mixins in typescript angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

> I'm trying to add custom functionality to extend lodash (note lodash
>   is npm'ed in).  But I keep getting a resolve error.

I've added a new file called lodash-mixins.js to my test project scripts folder e.g: project/frontend/src/web/Scripts/

```
var _ = require('lodash');
_.mixin({
    mixinLoaded function () { console.log("lodash mixins  are loaded");}
});
module.exports = _;
```

**Overview Folder Structure (simplified)**

> project/frontend/src/web
>
> ...frontend.web.csproj
>   ...angular-cli.json
>
> project/frontend/src/web/Scripts/
>
> ...lodash-mixins.js
>
> project/frontend/src/web/app/
>   ...app.module.ts

I've manually added my "lodash-mixins.js" to the "angular-cli.json"

```
"apps": [
    {
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

        etc
        "../node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js",
        "../Scripts/lodash-mixins.js",  //     <<<<< not picking up
        "../Scripts/global-error-handler.js",
      ],
```

Test by changing existing reference in one of my test.service.ts
from:

```
"import * as _ from 'lodash';"
```

to:

```
"import * as _ from 'lodash-mixins';"
```

I've rebuilt my c# solution for good measure.

> Run in CLI:  $ng build --watch

**ERROR in project/frontend/src/web/app/test/services/test.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash-mixins**

Any ideas?

Comment: A bit offtopic -- but may help eliminate the dependancy https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore

Comment: The real work is against an existing implementation dependant on lodash and also supporting many browsers. -but cheers anyway

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two different things here.

1) The "scripts" config for Angular CLI tells WebPack to include those JavaScrip files in the output bundle. It doesn't add those as importable modules. They get loaded as if you added `<script src="...">` tags to your HTML file (not exactly accurate, but gives the idea).

2) When you `import` using TypeScript it searches for the module. The reason it's giving the error is because the file isn't in one of the search paths. Had it actually found the file. It would have loaded it twice. Since you've already added it to the "scripts" config option.

JQuery, Lodash, etc.. etc.. can be loaded using modules or just plain global variables. When you add it to the "scripts" config, then I think this tells WebPack to load it in the global browser space.

When you use "import _ from 'lodash'" in TypeScript. You're actually resolving to the "@types/lodash" module which people often install so that TypeScript knows about the interface for lodash. When WebPack bundles everything for the browser it swaps out the @types for the real reference to the lodash instance.

So you have a couple of options.

1) Continue with what you've done. Add TypeScript definition file in the import path for your new module named "lodash-mixin". That module just defines the new interface with the new methods. The import will find that file and use it to compile the TypeScript, but the WebPack bundle will load your JS file in it's place.

2) Remove your "lodash-mixin" from the "scripts" config, then import using a relative path `import _ from '../Scripts/lodash-mixins'`. This is what I usually do. Note: You might have to add the file extension ".js"

3) Add your "Scripts" folder to your `tsconfig.json` as one of the type roots. This allows you to just use `import _ from 'lodash-mixins'`.

4) There is a way (and I forget exactly how), but you can tell TypeScript to alias lodash to your lodash-mixin so that all imports use that type instead. I don't recommend this approach.